# Is it true that a bounded non-decreasing subsequence must converge to at least its first term and at most its sup?

Tags: real-analysis

Coming from a lemma of Bolzano-Weierstrass, I feel as though this question is trivial. I just want to make sure that there are no faults in my logic here.

If the sequence is constant, then it must converge to whatever its first term is. If it converges to something less, then it is both not a constant sequence and not a non-decreasing one (contradiction).

If the sequence, $\{a_n\}$, is not constant and it converges to something less than its $sup$ (say $L$), then we have that every $a_n$ must be less than $L$ which is less than its $sup$. However, by the definition of $sup$, there must not exist an upper bound which is less than $sup(a_n)$ and this is how we arrive to the contradiction in this case.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It's even simpler: A bounded non-decreasing sequence converges to its supremum: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1166957/42969

Comment: You proved that *if* it converges then its limit *is* (always) its sup. You did not prove it converges.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is lacking in many places, and very confused.

> If it converges to something less, then it is both not a constant sequence and not a non-decreasing one (contradiction).

You are claiming here that if it converges to something else, then it is not a non-decreasing sequence. This is a true statement, sure, but you didn't prove it. The proof is simple, but without it, your argument is incomplete.

> If the sequence, $\{a_n\}$, is not constant and it converges to something less than its $sup$ (say $L$), then we have that every $a_n$ must be less than $L$ which is less than its $sup$.

Here, you **start** with an assumption that the sequence is non-constant **and** that it converges to something less that its supremum. But the claim you want to **prove** is that the sequence's limit is less than its supremum. You cannot just *assume* what you want to prove. Your argument here is logically completely empty.

---

I suggest you thoroughly rewrite your proof and use more standard mathematical terminology and argumentation. To that point, your proof should look something like this:

> **Statement**: If $\{a_n\}$ is a bounded non-decreasing sequence, then the limit $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$$ must be larger or equal to the first term of the sequence and smaller or equal to the supremum of the sequence.
> **Proof**: Let $\{a_n\}$ be a bounded non-decreasing sequence. Then, bla bla bla bla bla, therefore, $L \geq a_1$. Also, bla bla bla, therefore, $L\leq s$ where $s$ is the supremum of the sequence.

Of course, the bla bla bla's in the argument should be replaced by an actual proof. The first part of the proof could be something like this:

> Because $a_n$ is a non-decreasing sequence, we have $a_n \geq a_0$ for all $n$ (this can be shown by induction). It follows from the properties of limits that if $a_n>m$ for all $n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \geq m$, if the limit exists. Therefore, $L \geq a_0$.

I will leave the other half of the proof to you.